# To copy an image from an sdcard into res/drawable folder of the Android app

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard

I would like to know the possibility of copying an image from the sdcard in to the res/drawable folder of an Android application , these are very small Bitmaps located in an sdscard.

thanks in advance

Thank you for patiently answering my question , I am trying to locally store my bitmaps into the app local data location.

Comment: No. you can't do that. it is not possible to add images into drawable folder programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to edit res folder as it has to be filled up at compile time in order to let the compile generate the **R.java** file.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add image to drawable directory pro-grammatically.